# Nike+ FuelBand on 64-bit Ubuntu

Tags: 12.10, usb, virtualbox

I was recently gifted a Nike FuelBand.
To set it up and sync it, one must plug it into a computer running Windows or Mac. This is a little strange to me, as it supports bluetooth, but that's another issue.

I was hoping to sync with a Windows guest OS in VirtualBox but VirtualBox isn't detecting any USB devices when I plug it in.

dmesg tells me:

```
[ 3987.909749] usb 1-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[ 3988.021262] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=11ac, idProduct=6565
[ 3988.021265] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 3988.021266] usb 1-1.2: Product: FuelBand
[ 3988.021268] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Nike
[ 3988.021269] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: 00000001
[ 3988.026783] hid-generic 0003:11AC:6565.0005: hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Device [Nike FuelBand] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.2/input0
```

Most of the posts found Googling this issue were outdated or inconclusive. Something suggested that 64-bit Ubuntu can't see FuelBands for some reason.

Any troubleshooting ideas?

Comment: Have you told VirtualBox to capture the device?Have a look atthe devices menu.

Comment: Sadly, VirtualBox sees no USB devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

USB devices will be accessible if you actually *tell* virtualbox to claim them. Just choose your device from the `Devices` menu:

[image]

If that still does not work you will have to install [VirtualBox Guest Additions](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html) and you may have to add yourself to the `vboxusers` group:

```
sudo useradd -G vboxusers username
```

Comment: Between adding my user to that group, installing the latest virtualbox, and installing the guest additions, something worked. Thanks so much!